# why does my web browser version of java differ from the command line version

Tags: java, jvm

the Safari browser says I am running 7 -
[image: http://screencast.com/t/JJsAvYpKi]
But the command line says I am running 6:

```
[~/prg/ceylon-dist/samples/helloworld]$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_43"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_43-b01-447-11M4203)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.14-b01-447, mixed mode)
[~/prg/ceylon-dist/samples/helloworld]$
```

I checked `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/` and nothing there shows a 1.7 version at all.

Answer (score 2):

It's usually because the web version is a plugin to your browser, whilst java -version check the environment variable $JAVA_HOME$ and executes it with -version. So you will have to check your plugins for your browser.

Comment: Maybe I should've made my intention clearer. I want my command-line version of java to be 1.7. How do I do this?

Comment: Install the latest version of java, make sure $JAVA_HOME$ is pointing to that installation